# Ubuntu and w10 boot issues

Tags: 14.04

I tried to run ubuntu 14.04.3 as dual boot for windows 10 but now it says grub rescue. The error is no such device c6fe2095-c37c-4771-8743-5ab46133ac9d 
It does this every time I boot my PC.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into your live usb and Repair your boot with using [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)